# How to change hidden field to true when someone enter text in another field

Tags: javascript, django-templates

I'm working with django templates... want to do something like this in JS:

If someone entered a `text` to `textbox (id=super_text)`, I want to automatically change a `boolean field hiddenInput (id=super_boolean)` value to `True`.

I'm totally new in JS, was learning django backend for few months but I got my first project and one task is to do something like this in JS.

Can you help please? I will be thankfull (;

Comment: It's a little difficult to determine exactly what you're asking, which I think is probably a result of your lack of familiarity. With that said, I wouldn't expect a full solution to come out of this question. However, I think we can help get you on the path to find the answer, or at least learn enough to re-state the question in a manner more likely to help. First, I suggest you research events. Specifically, registering a `change` event listener on your input and reacting to to changes via a handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, `<input>`s can't be of type `boolean`, but the code below sets the text value of the hidden input to 'true'. (Even though I use the boolean value `true`, JS converts it to the string `"true"` when storing it in 'value', since the DOM knows that the input can only have a string as a value.)

```
<input type="text" id="super_text">
<input type="hidden" id="super_boolean">

<script>
    document.getElementById('super_text').addEventListener('keypress', function(){
        document.getElementById('super_boolean').value = true;
    })
</script>
```